# NSMutableDictionary causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to fix an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error that is being thrown when i access a NSMutableDictionary in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.  Right now it works when I fill ridesDict with a method loadHistoryFromDBExtended like so:

```
self.ridesDict = [self loadHistoryFromDBExtended]; 

NSLog(@"rides dict %@", self.ridesDict);
```

However, I don't want to call [self loadHistoryFromDBExtended] for every cell being loaded since the dictionary won't change so I tried moving:

```
self.ridesDict = [self loadHistoryFromDBExtended];
```

to viewDidLoad and now I am getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when i use:

```
NSLog(@"rides dict %@", self.ridesDict);
```

in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath. From what i've read it seems that i've got some memory retain/release issues but i can't seem to figure it out. I've tried [self.ridesDict retain] in viewDidLoad after the loadHistoryFromDBExtended method was called but that didn't help. I'm very new to this so I'd appreciate any pointers as to where to go.

Edit: Here is the loadHistoryFromDBExtended method:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)loadHistoryFromDBExtended
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDBPath]];

    if (![db open]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
        [pool release];
    }

    //get users
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM R order by date desc"]; //query provides result set

    //create result array
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    while ([rs next])
    {           
        NSMutableArray *usersDictArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        //look up names for id's
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"rNames"]];
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"dName"]];
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"date"]];
        [myDictionary setObject:usersDictArray forKey:[rs stringForColumn:@"rID"]];

        [usersDictArray release];
    }   

    //return usersArray;
    return myDictionary;

    [myDictionary release];

    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Does `loadHistoryFromDBExtended` return an object that’s owned by the caller? What’s the declaration of `ridesDict`? Is it a property? If so, is it a `retain` or `copy` property? Are you using synthesised accessors for the property or have you implemented custom accessors?

Comment: loadHistoryFromDBExtended is returning myDictionary that is declared in that method. ridesDict is declared in the interface and with @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *ridesDict; in .h and then @synthesize ridesDict; in the .m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous issues with how that method is implemented. In the check for whether the `db` could be opened or not, you release the autorelease pool, but then continue on to the rest of the code. I assume you would probably want to return `nil` at that point. In the `[rs next]` section, you create an `NSMutableArray` with `+array`, which creates an autoreleased object. As such, you shouldn't call `[usersDictArray release]`, as that would be over-releasing. (In each loop, the "temporary", autoreleased `usersDictArray` instances will be stored in the `pool` autorelease pool. When you call `[pool drain]`, the autorelease pool will send all of those temporary instances a `release` message). Towards the end, you have `return myDictionary;`, which causes the next 2 lines to never be reached. As a result, the autorelease pool you created would never be released (popped).

This is probably how I would implement it:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)loadHistoryFromDBExtended {   
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDBPath]];

    if (![db open]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
        [pool release];
        return nil; // I'm assuming you should return nil here
    }

    //get users; query provides result set
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM R order by date desc"];

    //create result array
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    while ([rs next])
    {           
        NSMutableArray *usersDictArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        //look up names for id's
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"rNames"]];
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"dName"]];
        [usersDictArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"date"]];
        [myDictionary setObject:usersDictArray forKey:[rs stringForColumn:@"rID"]];
        // [usersDictArray release];
    }   
    [pool drain];
    return [myDictionary autorelease];
}
```

(Note that how I implemented this assumes that the reasoning behind creating a local autorelease pool is for performance, and that there is a global `NSAutoreleasePool` in place to absorb the final `[myDictionary autorelease]` autoreleased object).

Comment: As mentioned under Lou Franco's response this indeed solves the problem as well as the leaks I was working on next.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this blog to help understand and debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

In order of easiness

1. Run a Build and Analyze -- do you get a clean build?  Look at what it's saying, but you can ignore leak problems for now -- look for problems of sending messages to released objects
2. Run with NSZombiesEnabled -- this makes objects never deallocate, and then complain if a message is sent to an object with retainCount of 0.
3. Enable Guard Malloc and then use the special GDB commands to inspect the integrity of the heap.  The problem is that you need to step through and do this before you crash to find the real problem.  It might crash somewhere else closer to your problem though

Comment: I was unaware of Build and Analyze. Very helpful, thank you. If you see my original comment i added the loadHistoryFromDBExtended method and i was releasing the array I was using to build the dictionary over each loop.  I think I was under the impression I had to release it to clear out the array before reusing it. I still have leaks but it works now and I can move forward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call:

```
[self.ridesDict retain];
```

before using the dictionary(maybe at class init). Don't forget to call:

```
[self.ridesDict release];
self.ridesDict = nil;
```

at dealloc.

Also check if you declare property in the header correctly. It must be:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ridesDict;
```

And add `@synthesize ridesDict;` to your class implementation.

Comment: You need to know how the @property was declared to know if this is right.  If it was with `retain`, for example, you should not do this.  The property assignment does a retain automatically, and assigning to nil, releases the old object.

Comment: But "forget to call retain" it's the most common reason of segmentation fault(aka EXC_BAD_ACCESS). A agree with you that it can be because you declare @property incorrectly. I forget that it's class varible, I thought(I don't know why) that it's local var. But if it's class var I recommend you to add retain in @property parametres